# What is access_hash in telegram API?

Tags: telegram, telethon, pyrogram, mtproto

When you `contacts.resolveUsername`, the result always contains both `id` and `access_hash`. It creates confusion for API users, as to why you are only able to resolve a user/chat/channel only by their `username` or by their `(id, access_hash)` pair (eg. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46736549/telegram-channel-how-to-get-access-hash) and [here](https://qna.habr.com/q/1199126)).

I tried searching the [telegram API homepage](https://core.telegram.org/) for info, but found no info about the meaning of `access_hash`.

I really am confused as to why you would need something more than `id` (or `username`). I'd like to know the nature of this `access_hash`:

1. Does it change over time?
2. Does it mean anything at all?
3. Is it safe to store in the database and be certain that it's
   constant?
4. Does it differ from account to account (e.g. I called
   `contacts.resolveUsername` from account #1 and then from #2, do I
   get the same number?)?

I know libs like `pyrogram`, `telethon` store this `access_hash` inside their local `sqlite` databases. This way they make it possible to call high level functions which require both `id` and `access_hash` using only `id`.

Comment: It's not limited to `resolveUsername`, `access_hash` is available on a lot of Types.

Comment: @0stone0 yeah, I know, but still it doesn't explain anything, unfortunately...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `access_hash` values commonly appear in Telegram's API when access to something should be "restricted" in some way. You can find `access_hash` for users, channels, or even [media objects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75489975/4759433).

I'll be using Telethon for the examples below, but the same applies to any library interacting with Telegram's API.

**Does it change over time?** Probably not. To the best of my knowledge, the `access_hash` does not change over time. I have not heard of any reports from users claiming that the `access_hash` has changed.

It is impossible to know for sure, as that would require access to the code the Telegram servers are using for this (and they could change their implementation at any time), but I've been working with Telegram for a very long time, and I can confidently say it likely never changes.

**Does it mean anything at all?** Not by itself. It's just a random-looking number. However, it is proof that you have access to a particular object, whether that's an user, channel, or media.

If the `access_hash` didn't exist, you could try guessing random IDs, which would for example make it possible to enumerate every user registered to Telegram!:

```py
for user_id in range(1_000_000):
    await client.get_entity(user_id)
```

Thankfully, the above code won't work, because in order to fetch user information, the `access_hash` needs to be known. But since it's random, and different for each account, it's pretty much impossible to guess. Thus, the `access_hash` keeps your account safe (as long as there's no way to "reach" it by other means, e.g. via a message forwarded from you, or your participation in public groups).

**Is it safe to store in the database and be certain that it's constant?** Yes. Telethon v1 for example stores the `access_hash` inside its `.session` file, which lets you use just the `id` to refer to users and channels, as long as the library has "seen" (and cached) their `access_hash` before.

If you've [saved an `access_hash` before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75087110/4759433), you can [reuse it later on your own](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75687721/4759433):

```py
from telethon import types

CHANNEL = types.InputPeerChannel(channel_id=..., access_hash=...)
```

**Does it differ from account to account?** Yes. The `access_hash` is unique to each account. For example, if Account_A fetches Channel_X, it may have `id=123, access_hash=456`. But if Account_B fetches the same Channel_X, it may have `id=123, access_hash=789`.

This means you cannot fetch an `access_hash` in Account_A and then try using it in Account_B, as it won't work (stickers seem to have been an exception at some point).

Every account will see the same ID for the same thing ([messages appear to be an exception](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75689058/4759433), but in reality they follow the same rules; they're duplicated for each account unless they occur inside a channel, so the "same" message can appear to have a different ID.)

Comment: hey, thank you much for explanation. What should I do, if my access_hash was compromized? is my still account safe?

Comment: It is fine to "leak" access hashes obtained from an account, because only that account can use them. Access hashes do not grant access to an entire account, only the object they're associated with.